# Initializer/Default value of filteredOptions: Observable<Options[]> and @ViewChild('auto') autocomplete: MatAutocomplete

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to have some default value for `filteredOptions: Observable<Options[]>;` and `@ViewChild('auto') autocomplete: MatAutocomplete;` but I do not know what it would be in all honesty.

**Please note when I say, a default value I mean an Initializer for the variables defined in the class.**

I am using `@ts-ignore` for now and it is working fine, but I also know that it is not the correct way of doing it.

This is my component.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatAutocomplete } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { map, Observable, startWith } from 'rxjs';

interface Options {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-primary-auto-complete',
  templateUrl: './primary-auto-complete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./primary-auto-complete.component.css'],
})
export class PrimaryAutoCompleteComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() label: string = '';
  @Input() placeholder: string = 'Start typing here';
  @Input() options: Options[] = [];
  @Input() ngStyle: { [Klass: string]: any } | null = null;

  @Input() autoSelectFormControl = new FormControl('');

  // @ts-ignore
  filteredOptions: Observable<Options[]>;

  // @ts-ignore
  @ViewChild('auto') autocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.autoSelectFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => this._filter(value || ''))
    );
  }

  // Clears the option if it is a wrong one
  onBlur = () => {
    if (!this.autocomplete.isOpen)
      this.options.some((item) => {
        if (item.key === this.autoSelectFormControl.value) return true;
        return false;
      })
        ? null
        : this.autoSelectFormControl.setValue('');
  };

  private _filter(value: string): {
    key: string;
    value: string;
  }[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter((item) =>
      item.key.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }
}
```

This is the HTML file.

```
<mat-form-field
  [ngStyle]="ngStyle"
  appearance="outline"
  class="primary-autoSelect"
  floatLabel="always"
>
  <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
  <input
    type="text"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    matInput
    [formControl]="autoSelectFormControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    (blur)="onBlur()"
  />
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
      [value]="option.value"
    >
      {{ option.key }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-error *ngIf="autoSelectFormControl.hasError('required')">
    {{ label }} is required
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="!autoSelectFormControl.hasError('required')">
    Please select a value from the list {{ label }}
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

What is the right way to provide a default value to such variables?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can use a "setter" in your input about autoSelectFormControl and options and remove the ngOnInit

```
  //define outside Options and autoSelectForms
  options:Options[];
  autoSelectFormControl:FormControl;

  @Input('options') set _options(value:any[]){
      this.options=value
      if (this.options && this.autoSelectFormControl)
          this.init()
  }

  @Input('autoSelectFormControl') set _autoSelect(value:FormControl){
      this.autoSelectFormControl=value;
      if (this.options && this.autoSelectFormControl)
          this.init()
  }

  init()
  {
    this.filteredOptions = this.autoSelectFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.autoSelectFormControl.value), //<--starts with "value"
      map((value) => this._filter(value || ''))
    );
  }
```

Comment: What about the viewChild part, how do I give it a default value?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between init and ngOnInit?

Comment: `init` is a function I call in the "setter"s of the inputs. I called "init" by convention, you can name it e.g. initialize or initializeForm. As we have two inputs and I want to not repeat code I made a function

Comment: I tried your solution but I still get the same warnings.

Comment: The diference between to make "something" in ngOnInit or in a "setter" of an Input is when is executed the function. is possible you executed the ngOnInit before you give value to the input

Comment: Note, that it essentially does not create any problems and does the job perfectly fine. But there is a warning that I don't have any initializers for the variables. I wish to remove that.